# Calculo Diario de ganancia R studio

Tags: r

Tengo los siguientes instrumentos por fecha y quisiera calcular la ganancia por precio diaria. Dejo un ejemplo de como seria:

```
instrument = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
price = c(12,13,29,20,87,24,14,78,46,98,23,67,25,88,27)
date = c("2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-01","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-03","2019-04-03","2019-04-03","2019-04-03","2019-04-03")
tabla1 = data.frame(instrument,price,date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `tidyverse` directamente y entendiendo que la ganancia diaria es la cotización del día menos la de día anterior, puedes hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

tabla1 %>% 
    arrange(instrument, date) %>%    # Es mandatorio orden por instrumento, fecha
    group_by(instrument) %>%         # Agrupamos por instrumento
    mutate(gan = price - lag(price)) # Obtenemos la ganancia del día
```

Con `lag(price)` podemos obtener el precio de la cotización anterior.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no logro interpretar bien "ganancia por precio diaria", si te refieres a la suma de `price`, se podría resolver fácilmente con `dplyr` y `lubridate`, la primera librería para el manejo de los datos y el segundo para las funciones de tiempo:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tabla1$date <- as_date(tabla1$date)
tabla1 %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(ganancia = sum(price))
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   date       ganancia
##   <date>        <dbl>
## 1 2019-04-01      161
## 2 2019-04-02      260
## 3 2019-04-03      230
```

Si lo que quieres es calcular el delta de un mismo instrumento entre fechas, quizás un doble bucle es una opción poco elegante, pero efectiva:

```
instr <- unique(tabla1$instrument)
fechas <- unique(tabla1$date)

res <- list()

for(i in 1:2){
  res[[i]] <- list()
  for(j in seq_along(instr)){
    res[[i]][[j]] <- data.frame(Fecha = fechas[i+1], instrumento = instr[j], Delta = tabla1[(tabla1$instrument == instr[j]) & (tabla1$date == fechas[i+1]), 'price'] - tabla1[(tabla1$instrument == instr[j]) & (tabla1$date == fechas[i]), 'price'])
  }
}

do.call(rbind,do.call(rbind,res))
##         Fecha instrumento Delta
## 1  2019-04-02           1    12
## 2  2019-04-03           1    -1
## 3  2019-04-02           2     1
## 4  2019-04-03           2    53
## 5  2019-04-02           3    49
## 6  2019-04-03           3   -53
## 7  2019-04-02           4    26
## 8  2019-04-03           4    42
## 9  2019-04-02           5    11
## 10 2019-04-03           5   -71
```